# Deploy ASP.Net site, only error 500

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7

I've had this problem in the past, and the solution was always a configuration issue, or needed to run aspnet_regiis -i or something.  But aspnet_regiis doesn't fix the problem, and I can't find anything that would be wrong in any configuration file.

Is there some log that I'm not looking in that would tell me exactly what "500 - Internal server error" I'm actually hitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the `500 - Internal Server Error` page that looks like this that you're seeing:

[image]

Then you can have IIS7 to pass the detailed error back to the client by configuring the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

If you're using IE then remember to turn off *Show friendly HTTP error messages* (in Tools -> Options -> Advanced), but you knew that already :).

If that still doesn't shed any light on the problem then you can use Failed Request Tracing which is a very effective diagnostic tool:

> [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/)

Comment: I'll do this today.  As far as me knowing to turn off the friendly HTTP error messages thing in IE, I vaguely remember that, but thanks for the vote of confidence that I'd remember at the right time.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Administrative Tools / Computer Management / Event Viewer / Application Log

I think..  Not in front of a windows box right now.  You should see in that log some events that correspond to your 500 errors.  They will give you more info.

Comment: I checked there (just now to make sure) and I don't see anything.  I see several errors, but none that are even close to when I should be seeing them (in the past 30 minutes).  I checked Application, System, etc.

Comment: @Matt probably you can check for some log info at website logs. Right click on website (in iis)-> properties->in website tab at the bottom see properties click on it->Logging properties , here at bottom you get log file path where all logs can be found.

Comment: @Pramodtech -- I checked there, too, just now, and it is showing the request, and that it responded with a 500 error.  No reason why it did, just that it did.  I'll dig into the logging options to see if I can make it output some more details.

Comment: Try checking your ISAPI and CGI restrictions, as well as Handler Mappings.  Try creating and hitting a dummy.html and a dummy.aspx file and see if there is a difference.